# What will be best practice in case of OTP one time password

Tags: android, post, get, one-time-password

I am adding OTP in Android app . With one edit text user will enter his mobile no will get otp with sms gateway provider .
Please tell me for above condition what will be best method to send otp and verify otp ? Why ?
GET or POST method ?

Comment: If you think GET or POST is your biggest issue, then you don't know nearly enough about http, security, or webservices to implement this securely.

Comment: No , I have asked what is the best method for described situation .

Comment: Yes.  And that question is utterly unimportant in the large scheme of what you're doing.  The only difference between the two will be about 1 line of code on your server (if that) and whether or not phone numbers appear in the logs.  Its unimportant.  But if you didn't know this, you shouldn't be implementing this functionality.

Comment: For security of sensitive data, we can use encryption over transport layer.

Comment: If you think that's all that matters, you're proving my point.

Comment: Start your reading here:  https://www.theregister.co.uk/2016/12/06/2fa_missed_warning/    Basically one time passwords via sms are considered insecure and should almost never be used.

Comment: It means that you are saying that it does not matter either  use GET or POST ?

Comment: Yes, either with POST or GET the idea of OTP over an unsecured channel like SMS is unsafe.

Comment: What is the safe to authenticate ?

Comment: @Gabe Sechan using get method ,if any one knows backend api url then he can start sending otp with mobile no many times .

Answer (score 0):

To verify OTP you should use POST as in GET the parameters are visible, also to make it secure you can use https connection for verify OTP service (provided your webservice supports it) . For further security you can encrypt your OTP at client side and decrypt it at server side before verification.

Comment: Actually neither are visible to the outside if you use HTTPS.  And then you don't need to encrypt it either, as HTTPS encrypts it for you.  Then the only visibility problem you might have is if your server automatically logs all requests, as with get the number may be in the logs.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan using get method ,if any one knows backend api url then he can start sending otp with mobile no many times

Comment: @user6313669 You can do that with either method.  Nothing about POST prevents it.

Comment: Okay do you know how can prevent this ?